# ¿Cómo mostrar y actualizar un option de un select con datos ingresados en una base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Soy nueva usando PHP y necesito saber cómo mostrar un valor en un select de acuerdo a qué valor está seleccionado o ingresado en la base de datos.
La tabla "Equipo" está relacionada con la tabla "Departamento", Muchos equipos pueden pertenecer a un sólo Departamento, por lo tanto la tabla "Equipo" guarda el ID del Departamento.
Por ahora mi código está así:

```
 <?php
 require_once("cn.php");
 include ("menuadmin.php");
 if (isset($_POST["updatequipo"])) {
$updatequipo=$_POST["update"];
$update_descrip=$_POST["update_descrip"];
$update_depto=$_POST["update_depto"];

if (isset($updatequipo)) {
  for ($i=0; $i < count($updatequipo) ; $i++) {
    $sql="UPDATE `equipo`
          SET `descrip` = '$update_descrip[$i]',
            `depto` = '$update_depto[$i]'
          WHERE `idequipo` = '$updatequipo[$i]';";
          $conn->query($sql);
        }
      }
?>
<script language='javascript'>
 swal({
  text: 'Datos actualizados correctamente',
  icon: 'success',
  button: 'Aceptar'
   })
 </script>
   <?php
 }
 ?>
<div class="table-responsive">
 <div align="center">
 <p class="display-5">Detalles de los Equipos</p>
<form method="POST" name="form2">
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-light" width="600">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        <th scope="col">Descripción del Equipo</th>
        <th scope="col">Departamento</th>
        <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
      $sql="SELECT
                `departamento`.`departamento`
                , `departamento`.`id_departamento`
                , `equipo`.`descrip`
                , `equipo`.`idequipo`
            FROM
                `res_equipo`
                INNER JOIN `departamento`
                    ON (`res_equipo`.`depto` = `departamento`.`id_departamento`);";
      $rs=$conn->query($sql);
      while($fila=$rs->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='equipo[]' value='$fila[idequipo]'>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='update_descrip[]' class='form-control' value='$fila[descrip]' required>";
        echo "<td><select class='form-control' name='update_depto[]'>";
        if ($fila[departamento]=="ComputaciÃ³n") {
          $selected="selected";
          echo "<option value='1'".$selected.">Computación</option>";
          echo "<option value='2'>Eléctrica</option>";
          echo "<option value='3'>Área Básica</option>";
          echo "<option value='4'>Administración</option>";
          echo "<option value='5'>Patrimonio</option>";
          echo "<option value='7'>Servicio Desarrollo Prof.</option>";
        }
        if ($fila[departamento]=="ElÃ©ctrica") {
          $selected="selected";
          echo "<option value='1'>Computación</option>";
          echo "<option value='2'".$selected.">Eléctrica</option>";
          echo "<option value='3'>Área Básica</option>";
          echo "<option value='4'>Administración</option>";
          echo "<option value='5'>Patrimonio</option>";
          echo "<option value='7'>Servicio Desarrollo Prof.</option>";
        }
        if ($fila[departamento]=="Ãrea bÃ¡sica") {
          $selected="selected";
          echo "<option value='1'>Computación</option>";
          echo "<option value='2'>Eléctrica</option>";
          echo "<option value='3'".$selected.">Área Básica</option>";
          echo "<option value='4'>Administración</option>";
          echo "<option value='5'>Patrimonio</option>";
          echo "<option value='7'>Servicio Desarrollo Prof.</option>";
        }
        if ($fila[departamento]=="AdministraciÃ³n") {
          $selected="selected";
          echo "<option value='1'>Computación</option>";
          echo "<option value='2'>Eléctrica</option>";
          echo "<option value='3'>Área Básica</option>";
          echo "<option value='4'".$selected.">Administración</option>";
          echo "<option value='5'>Patrimonio</option>";
          echo "<option value='7'>Servicio Desarrollo Prof.</option>";
        }
        if ($fila[departamento]=="Patrimonio") {
          $selected="selected";
          echo "<option value='1'>Computación</option>";
          echo "<option value='2'>Eléctrica</option>";
          echo "<option value='3'>Área Básica</option>";
          echo "<option value='4'>Administración</option>";
          echo "<option value='5'".$selected.">Patrimonio</option>";
          echo "<option value='7'>Servicio Desarrollo Prof.</option>";
        }
        if ($fila[departamento]=="Servicio Desarrollo prof.") {
          $selected="selected";
          echo "<option value='1'>Computación</option>";
          echo "<option value='2'>Eléctrica</option>";
          echo "<option value='3'>Área Básica</option>";
          echo "<option value='4'>Administración</option>";
          echo "<option value='5'>Patrimonio</option>";
          echo "<option value='7'".$selected.">Servicio Desarrollo Prof.</option>";
        }
        echo "<td><input type='hidden' value='$fila[idequipo]' name='update[]'>";
        echo "</tr>";
      }
      ?>
  </table>
  <input align="center" type="submit" name="updatequipo" value="Actualizar Equipo" class="btn btn-info">
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

¿Pero en el caso de que no sepa cuántos departamentos hay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas repetir el codigo tantas veces.  Puedes hacer lo mismo en una sola vez asi:

```
<?php
 require_once("cn.php");
 include ("menuadmin.php");
 if (isset($_POST["updatequipo"])) {
$updatequipo=$_POST["update"];
$update_descrip=$_POST["update_descrip"];
$update_depto=$_POST["update_depto"];

if (isset($updatequipo)) {
  for ($i=0; $i < count($updatequipo) ; $i++) {
    $sql="UPDATE `equipo`
          SET `descrip` = '$update_descrip[$i]',
            `depto` = '$update_depto[$i]'
          WHERE `idequipo` = '$updatequipo[$i]';";
          $conn->query($sql);
        }
      }
?>
<script language='javascript'>
 swal({
  text: 'Datos actualizados correctamente',
  icon: 'success',
  button: 'Aceptar'
   })
 </script>
   <?php
 }
 ?>
<div class="table-responsive">
 <div align="center">
 <p class="display-5">Detalles de los Equipos</p>
<form method="POST" name="form2">
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-light" width="600">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        <th scope="col">Descripción del Equipo</th>
        <th scope="col">Departamento</th>
        <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
      $sql="SELECT
                `departamento`.`departamento`
                , `departamento`.`id_departamento`
                , `equipo`.`descrip`
                , `equipo`.`idequipo`
            FROM
                `res_equipo`
                INNER JOIN `departamento`
                    ON (`res_equipo`.`depto` = `departamento`.`id_departamento`);";
      $rs=$conn->query($sql);
      while($fila=$rs->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='equipo[]' value='$fila[idequipo]'>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='update_descrip[]' class='form-control' value='$fila[descrip]' required>";
        echo "<td><select class='form-control' name='update_depto[]'>";

          $selected="selected";
          $valor = $fila[departamento];
          echo "<option value='1'" . ($valor=="ComputaciÃ³n" ? $selected : '') . ">Computación</option>";
          echo "<option value='2'" . ($valor=="ElÃ©ctrica" ? $selected : '') . ">Eléctrica</option>";
          echo "<option value='3'" . ($valor=="Ãrea bÃ¡sica" ? $selected : '') . ">Área Básica</option>";
          echo "<option value='4'" . ($valor=="AdministraciÃ³n" ? $selected : '') . ">Administración</option>";
          echo "<option value='5'" . ($valor=="Patrimonio" ? $selected : '') . ">Patrimonio</option>";
          echo "<option value='7'" . ($valor=="Servicio Desarrollo prof." ? $selected : '') . ">Servicio Desarrollo Prof.</option>";                   

        echo "<td><input type='hidden' value='$fila[idequipo]' name='update[]'>";
        echo "</tr>";
      }
      ?>
  </table>
  <input align="center" type="submit" name="updatequipo" value="Actualizar Equipo" class="btn btn-info">
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

En este codigo utilizo un operador ternario, que no es mas que un `if` simplificado.  Puedes leer mas acerca de eso aqui: http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php.  Tambien deberias revisar la codificadion de tu base de datos.  Puedes asegurarte que sea codificacion `UTF` haciendo algo como `mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");` en tu codigo.  Esto sirve para que las palabras con acentos sean guardadas correctamente. Si no sabes cuantos departamentos hay, crearias un bucle siguiendo la misma logica.

Comment: Dice que es nueva en PHP. Al menos explica que estás usando un operador ternario para resolver su problema, indicando el enlace del Manual donde se pueda documentar. Yo le indicaría también que tiene un serio problema con la codificación que debería resolver. No es bueno conformarse con hacer comparaciones con valores como este: `ComputaciÃ³n` , mañana eso puede ser otra cosa, si no se codificado todo correctamente revisando por qué ese dato está viniendo así de mal.

Comment: Lo de las comparaciones sólo lo hice porque estuve usando eso con el campo "estado" de mi tabla "equipo" usando valores 1=Activo 0=No Activo... Sólo supuse que una forma de hacer lo que quería era usando los if...

Comment: Hola @MellieRR, tu codigo funciona correctamente, es solo que siempre es bueno evitar la repeticion.  Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español.